# Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined

Tags: plone, openlayers-3

Environment: Plone 5.0.6, OpenLayers 3.11.0

I want using sample codes at https://github.com/GaborFarkas/mastering_openlayers3/archive/v1.1.zip to work within my Plone instance. You can see the custom package code at https://github.com/l34marr/my.map/tree/world-capitals that tries to read a GeoJSON file and display features on the VectorLayer.

At first I run into the following errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined
>
> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { ...

[image: JS Errors When Running the Browser View]

By guessing, a workaround seems fix the above issue: changing the order of [two lines in main_template.pt](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/main_template.pt#L37) as follows:

```
<metal:javascriptslot define-slot="javascript_head_slot" />
<div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.scripts" />
```

This way, the errors are gone and everything seems working as expected. See the screenshot for reference.

[image: Seems Working]

Question: What causes the error? What's the recommended hints to debug and fix the issue?